# Are updates to libapache2-mod-php5 update causing apache to crash?

Tags: apache2, php, unattended-upgrades

The latest security updates on  **5/25/2016** seem to have cause `apache-php5 module` to fail loading. Anyone else seeing this? Reboot resolves but here is the error detail. Possibly this security update should not be "unattended"?

```
apache2: Syntax error on line 210 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Syntax error on line 1 of /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/php5.load: Cannot load /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp5.so into server: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6: symbol __strtold_nan, version GLIBC_PRIVATE not defined in file libc.so.6 with link time reference
```

Comment: We just had a bunch of servers crash from this update as well with the same error message in our logs. Restarting apache seems to resolve the issue though.

Answer (score 1):

I just saw this on both my 12.04 LTS servers.  "sudo apt-get upgrade" caused the web server to stop.  A simple "sudo service apache2 start" appears to have fixed the issue here.

I similarly got an error:

```
[Wed May 25 11:49:42 2016] [error] (9)Bad file descriptor: apr_socket_accept: (client socket)
apache2: Syntax error on line 210 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Syntax error on line 1 of /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/php5.load: Cannot load /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp5.so into server: /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libm.so.6: symbol __strtold_nan, version GLIBC_PRIVATE not defined in file libc.so.6 with link time reference
```

My 16.04 LTS servers seem unaffected.

EDIT: I previously reported this was affecting a 14.04LTS server.  Upon further investigation, it's actually another 12.04LTS server.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the relevant Launchpad bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/eglibc/+bug/1585614

Comment: What's this link about?

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens This is the bug report that was sent to the Ubuntu developers reporting this problem. You can see what the current state of the bug is and what the developers are doing to fix it, and (if you have a Launchpad account) you can subscribe to be notified when they fix it.